# Variable wont update in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

```
void Neededtype_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (neededkey == e.KeyCode)
    {
        neededtype.ForeColor   = Color.FromName("Gray");
        mostanikari++;

        if (mostanikari == 2)
        {
            neededtype.Text = "work";
        }

        neededtype.SelectionStart = mostanikari;
        kovikari = mostaniszo[mostanikari].ToString();
        neededtype.SelectionLength = neededtype.Text.Length;
        neededtype.SelectionColor = Color.FromName("Blue");

        if (mostanikari == neededtype.Text.Length)
        {
            //random word gen here
        }
    }

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

- `neededkey`: the key that needs to be pressed
- `mostanikari`: is an int that keeps track of which letter we are on now
- `kovikari`: is the string neededkey is calculated from
- `neededtype`: is the richtextbox i am displaying the word in

This code over here is trying to add +1 to `mostanikari` and then move forward with the selection

Comment: Where and how is `mostanikari` declared and defined? You should use `this.` when using fields to make it clear when an identifier refers to a local or a field.

Comment: I doubt `InitializeComponent();` should be called on each key down. Why do you need it there ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be calling `InitializeComponent()` when you press a key because this will reset the object to its default state. Which is why you don't see a change in the winform.

```
void Neededtype_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if (neededkey == e.KeyCode)
    {
        neededtype.ForeColor   = Color.FromName("Gray");
        mostanikari++;
        if (mostanikari == 2)
        {
            neededtype.Text = "work";
        }
        neededtype.SelectionStart = mostanikari;
        kovikari = mostaniszo[mostanikari].ToString();
        neededtype.SelectionLength = neededtype.Text.Length;
        neededtype.SelectionColor = Color.FromName("Blue");

        if (mostanikari == neededtype.Text.Length)
        {
            //random word gen here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer